# sa1650: get custom dictionary or disable rule in whole solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

In my project, we decided to write the documention in our mother tongue. But with the new style cop, we get the problem, that our comments were misspelled.
Since no one wants to write a whole custom dictionary for style cop, I want to know, if there is a custom dictionary for german.

Another possible solution would be, to turn this rule off. But since we have approximately 60 projects in our solution, I need to turn this rule off for the whole solution. How would I do that?

If anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, to put a `Settings.StyleCop`-file next to the `sln`. Then you can configure these StyleCop settings with the StyleCopSettingsEditor.

This way, you can turn specific rules off for the whole solution.